# xampp mysql doesn't run on port 3306

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I am trying to run xampp MYSQL Database on port 3306, but it gets neither started, nor shown any errors on application log. Application log only shows `Starting MySQL Database...` ProFTPD and Apache Web Servers are running, but MYSQL is always stopped. 
If I change port number to lets say 3308, I can run it but I have to run the mysql on port 3306 because my project team members are using port 3306.

A result from terminal: `ps -ax | grep mysqld`

```
    652 ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql --pid-file=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/my-mbp.pid
  793 ??         0:11.57 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles --datadir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/plugin/ --user=mysql --log-error=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/my-mbp.err --pid-file=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/my-mbp.pid --socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3308
 4589 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysqld
```

How can I force xampp mysql to run on port 3306? XAMPP Version: 5.5.38-1

Comment: check the my.ini file in the mysql dir. It should be there I think

Comment: Is there something already bound to port 3306?

Comment: I wrote `ps -ax | grep 3306`, result was `5547 ttys000    0:00.00 grep 3306`

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is a bit old, I hope I don't violate rules. But I recently had this problem and after some discussion with my brother, he told me that I might had mysql running with brew, which I had.

So in the terminal I typed brew services stop mysql. And after that I was able to start mysql with xampp with port 3306

Comment: Excellent!! I forgot that I started the brew one!! thanks a ton @greger.

Answer (score 0):

In `/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini` chek these settings

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "/opt/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

If your mysql server is not starting, check what process is using the port using `netstat` and reconfigure that service to use another port.

Comment: What happesn if you run `/xampp/mysql_start` ? do you see more output and logging?

Comment: I did `sudo ./xampp startmysql`, the result was `XAMPP: Starting MySQL...fail.`
`XAMPP:  Another MySQL daemon is already running.`

Comment: Use `top` to find the other mysql process and kill it (if no one else is using that instance?

Comment: How can I use `top`?

Comment: in a terminal type: `top`, then note the process id of the mysql process that is running and use `kill #processId` to stop the process. Type Q to quit TOP mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem but then with MAMP. Which OS are you on? If you're on MAC OS Sierra or higher you should do this.

- Go to system preferences
- Scroll down and find MySQL
- Stop the MySQL server
- You should be good to go now

If this doesn't work you will need to delete the MySQL version from your computer and reinstall it. Don't forget to make a backup. More information about removing MySQL can be found here: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x.

Make sure you don't have other databases running on port 3306 like Postgress or other DB's. You can check this with `netstat -ap tcp | grep -i "listen"` more can be found on StackOverflow I guess.

Goodluck, if you have any remarks or questions let me know.